# MVC2 HTML Linking - Is this proper, or is there a better way?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, hyperlink

I haven't done MVC2 (or any MVC really) in over a year and while this works, I want to make sure it's the best way.

I have a "splash" page that allows the user to choose what they want to work on; Interfaces, Events, Parameters or Tasks.  The HTML is:

```
<a href="/Interfaces/Index">
    <div id="homeInterfaces" class="homeLinks">
        <h1>Interfaces</h1>
        <h2>Create, Edit or Delete Interfaces</h2>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="/Tasks/Index">
    <div id="homeTasks" class="homeLinks">
        <h1>Tasks</h1>
        <h2>Create, Edit or Delete Tasks</h2>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="/Parameters/Index">
    <div id="homeParameters" class="homeLinks">
        <h1>Parameters</h1>
        <h2>Create, Edit or Delete Parameters</h2>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="/Events/Index">
    <div id="homeEvents" class="homeLinks">
        <h1>Events</h1>
        <h2>Create, Edit or Delete Events</h2>
    </div>
</a>
```

The links work and go to the appropriate pages, but for whatever reason, I'm not sure if this is the proper way to go about it.  I have controllers for each, the proper folders with the Index views for each.  I don't think I should be using Html.ActionLink, but maybe there's something else I should be using.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why this could be wrong. Stop worrying about what is right and just create the product, and if you are worried about something ask a specific question.

Comment: Can you improve your title to be something more useful to others? Right now it's "Is this proper or is there a better way?" which doesn't give future users any clue whether this question will help them.

Comment: @RaymondChen - Is that better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be using a helper for these. This will ensure that your generated links use the appropriate routes, which will make your life much easier in the future if you do anything fancy with your URLs or deploy to a non-root path (i.e. `/`)

In your case, the easiest solution is to replace the URL with `@Url.Action`. I'd use that over `Html.ActionLink` because `Html.ActionLink` doesn't let you easily linkify content more complicated than simple text (e.g. your html).

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Interfaces")">
  <div id="homeInterfaces" class="homeLinks">
    <h1>Interfaces</h1>
    <h2>Create, Edit or Delete Interfaces</h2>
  </div>
</a>
```

If you're not using Razor, go switch to that first. It's worth it. Or drop the `@` sign and add some `<%= ... %>`.

As @MichalFran notes, though, if it's working now, you can always just start following this advice in the future and revisit what you've already done when/if you need to down the road.

Comment: +1 I also prefer using Url.Action in the href attribute instead of Html.ActionLink. Is more clear what the rendered HTML output will look like.

Comment: @danludwig thanks for the comment, which prompted me to fix `Url.Action<del>Link</del>`

Comment: Thanks, that does seem more appropriate.  I'll have to investigate Razor to see what advantages it has.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not standalone. I am posting it as a supplement to [Michael Haren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079168/304832), which I like.

The other thing I would like to add as a "thought" is [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC). I am a big fan of it, because it can help you get rid of more "magic strings" in both `@Url.Action` and `@Html.Action`. For example, take Michael's example code:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Interfaces")">
    ...
```

Using T4MVC, you can get rid of the magic strings, and render the route URL like so:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Interfaces.Index())">
```

Then, if you ever rename the `InterfacesController` or rename / change the signature of your `Index()` action method, **the view will fail to compile instead of getting a 404 at runtime**.

Another cool thing is that you can pass parameters to the routing engine as if you were invoking the action method:

```
public ActionResult ById(int entityId) { ... } 

<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Interfaces.Index(Model.EntityId))">
    ...
```

I don't know why more people don't post about this!

Comment: +1 I like the T4MVC stuff, too. I'm a little surprised it isn't built into MVC (yet?)